# Python C API, High reference count for new Object

Tags: python, automatic-ref-counting, python-c-api

I'm just trying to understand how to deal with the reference counts when using the Python C API.

I want to call a Python function in C++, like this:

```
PyObject* script;
PyObject* scriptRun;
PyObject* scriptResult;

// import module
script = PyImport_ImportModule("pythonScript");
// get function objects
scriptRun = PyObject_GetAttrString(script, "run");
// call function without/empty arguments
scriptResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(scriptRun, NULL);

if (scriptResult == NULL)
    cout << "scriptResult  = null" << endl;
else
    cout << "scriptResult  != null" << endl;

cout << "print reference count: " << scriptResult->ob_refcnt << endl;
```

The Python code in pythonScript.py is very simple:

```
def run():
    return 1
```

The documentation of "PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs" says that you get a new reference as return value. So I would expect "scriptResult" to have a reference count of 1. However the output is:

```
scriptResult  != null
print reference count: 72
```

Furthermore I would expect a memory leak if I would do this in a loop without decreasing the reference count. However this seems not to happen.

Could someone help me understand?

Kind regards!

Comment: A follow-up question: Thanks to @ecatmur and @KayZhu I now understand why there is no memory leak. Nevertheless if I run this code in a long loop my complete os crushes anyway. The reference count to `1` is increasing, every iteration, but I do not see why this should cause a system failure.

Comment: Are you looping until `ob_refcnt` cycles back through 0? The reference count of 1 fluctuates a lot. When you wrap around past 0, normal operations could `Py_DECREF` to 0 and cause `int` 1 to get deallocated, followed quickly by a segfault. Try it with a less common interned `int` such as 13.

Comment: At least, I was not even looping until 'sys.maxint' (which is '9223372036854775807' on my system). Today it seems I cannot reproduce the error and I guess I should stop trying to shoot my working desktop down. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ecatmur is right, numbers and strings are interned in Python, so instead you can try with a simple `object()` object.

A simple demo with [`gc`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html):

```
import gc


def run():
    return 1

s = run()
print len(gc.get_referrers(s))  # prints a rather big number, 41 in my case

obj = object()
print len(gc.get_referrers(obj))  # prints 1

lst = [obj]
print len(gc.get_referrers(obj))  # prints 2

lst = []
print len(gc.get_referrers(obj))  # prints 1 again
```

---

A bit more: when CPython creates a new object, it calls a C macro [`_Py_NewReference`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e7706bdaaa0d/Include/object.h#l562) to initialize the reference count to 1. Then uses `Py_INCREF(op)` and `Py_DECREF(op)` to increase and decrease the reference count.

Comment: Thank  you! However if I replace s by a number like 123456.7565 I still get 1 referrer. If I do it in my python code called by my C++ code I still get 2. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @user1774143: Are returning `123456.7565` from the function `run()`? If so the 2nd reference is the code object's tuple of constants: `run.__code__.co_consts`.

Comment: Ah I understand. In this tuple all constants within the method are stored so I have one additional reference here. Thanks!

Comment: @user1774143 it is also referenced by the tuple: (None, 123456.7565)

Answer (score 5):

The confusion is that small integers (also `True`, `False`, `None`, single-character strings, etc.) are *interned* ( ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) ), which means that wherever they are used or obtained in a program the runtime will try to use the same object instance:

```
>>> 1 is 1
True
>>> 1 + 1 is 2
True
>>> 1000 + 1 is 1001
False
```

This means that when you write `return 1`, you're returning an already existing `int` object instance with (as you've seen) a considerable reference count.  Because the same instance is used elsewhere, failing to dereference it won't result in a memory leak.

If you change your script to `return 1001` or `return object()` then you will see an initial reference count of 1 and a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I did not know about the small integer thing! However, if I change the return value to 1001, or some other funny value, I still get a reference count of 2 instead of 1.

Comment: okay I see now that for returning object() the reference count is in fact 1!